# Missing functions in protobuf generated file

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

I compiled the following file lsp.proto

```
message LSPMessage
{
required uint32 connid=1; // Connection ID
required uint32 seqnum=2; // Sequence Num
required bytes payload=3; // Payload
}
```

In another file I included lsp.pb.h. However when I compile it says LSPMESSAGE_*INIT not declared, unable to find lspmessage*_pack(). These functions are not in the generated files either. Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using the protobuf-c compiler with the C++ API.